# Boto for amazon s3 allows no access to the key I just created

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have the credentials to an Amazon s3 bucket of the form:

```
<AWS_ACCESS_KEY> = "some junk"
<AWS_SECRET_KEY> = "some more junk"
<bucketname> = "mybucket"
```

I used boto to access the bucket:

```
import boto
s3=boto.connect_s3(<AWS_ACCESS_KEY>, <AWS_SECRET_KEY>)
bucket = s3.get_bucket('mybucket')
mykey = bucket.new_key('test_key')
mykey.set_contents_from_string('this is test content')
```

and exit ipython. So far so good, at the s3 console I see a new text file with the correct content.

Restart Ipython, and go through the same steps retrieving the bucket. At that point, I do

```
bucket.get_key('test_key')
```

which leads to a 403 error:

```
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

How is it possible that I do not have access to the resource I just created? And, how do I fix this?

Comment: what are the permissions on the bucket? it's possible that you are allowed only to put objects not to get objects

Comment: The only permissions available on the bucket (in the console) are list, upload/delete, view permissions, and edit permissions. Those are all checked.
There is nothing like a 'read' permission that I can see though

Comment: It works for me when I run the above code in my account. This suggests a permission problem not related to the object itself (eg might be on the Bucket or IAM user). Check your Bucket Policy (click 'Edit Bucket Policy', preferably it would be blank so it would only show 'Add Bucket Policy'), and check what IAM permissions you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your code as I have reproduced it without any errors and even created the bucket with Boto. The code and interaction with the API are both solid. The issue is likely related to how you are managing AWS secrets locally or the IAM policy.

```
Here is your code with some slight modifications:

import boto

s3=boto.connect_s3()
c_bucket = s3.create_bucket('yodas')
g_bucket = s3.get_bucket('yodas')
mykey = bucket.new_key('test_key')
mykey.set_contents_from_string('this is test content')


>>> print mykey
<Key: yodas,test_key>

>>> bucket.get_key('test_key')
<Key: yodas,test_key>
```

You may want to create a bucket and policy at the same time. You can assign an IAM user, policy and bucket with a simple script to the API. Then you have a specific policy for that user.

```
my_bucket = "yodas"
my_iam_name = "myuser"
my_policy_name = "yodaspolicy"

policy_json = '''{
    "Statement":[{
        "Sid":"RandomStringIdentifier",
        "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
            ],
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::%s/*"
        }]
}''' % my_bucket

response = iam.create_user(my_iam_name)
iam.put_user_policy(my_iam_name, my_policy_name, policy_json)
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed there was a problem with the IAM policy. The issue was that the user logging in was not the root user, I added extra user privileges and now it works.